# "Error: Automation server can't create object" for Msxml2.ServerXmlHttp in Windows Server 2008

Tags: javascript, msxml6

I am getting this error:
"Error: Automation server can't create object"

when I tried to create an object of  Msxml2.ServerXmlHttp using java script in Windows Server 2008.

This error goes away if I make this IE setting change "Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe."

but why is this IE setting change required? the same works without any setting change in Windows 7.

Thanks
Venkatesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happend because this particular ActiveX control has been tagged as 'Unsafe for scripting'.